# Create a reverse relationship to two models

Tags: django, postgresql, materialized-views, postgresql-13, django-3.2

I have a model `User`. For performance and other reasons I have to split this Model and its table into two, `UserA` and `UserB`. I decided to use materialized views (with the help of [django-pgviews](https://github.com/mikicz/django-pgviews)). Now what IS easy is to query the data of `UserA` which is already in the table, like the username or password. What doesn't work are reverse relationships. Let's say I have a `Checkout` model and in this:

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='checkouts')
```

When I try to access `user.checkouts`, it of course throws an error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'checkouts' into field`.

So how can I create a reverse relationship which is accessible from multiple models? I thought about using [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) but this seems a bit much for this use case, especially because UserA and UserB are just views and have the same columns.

Comment: "user.checkouts" - is "user" referencing to specific row of model "User"? Could you please post your models.py

Comment: "user.checkouts" is the reverse relationship defined via `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='checkouts')`, more verbose: `UserA.objects.filter(pk=1).first().checkouts.all()`